# Convert string value with '$' into double

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Have not found a similar question on SO yet (regarding '$').

I'm following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3), trying to expand a pre-existing method to convert strings into doubles. The general structure of the code looks like so:

```
string str = "$1,000.00";
double output;
var success = Double.TryParse(
    str
    , NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
        | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint
        | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
        | NumberStyles.AllowExponent
        | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol
    , null // CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
           // or NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo break conversion with '$'..
    , out output
    );
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}, {2}", str, output, success);
```

This works. The problem I'm getting is dealing with the '$' character when the`IFormatProvider` [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of the `Double.TryParse()` method is set to either `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`

(i.e. replace `null` in the method call with one of the commented out variables)

Why is that? Do I really need to set that parameter as one of those to suit the internationalization of the input strings? The initial implemenation of this method had the parameter set as `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` which breaks the conversion of a string that contains '$'.

Comment: Are you asking why or are you asking how to fix it?  How to fix it is on topic.  Why MS made the decision to make it work that way is not really on topic, unless some official documentation behind the reasoning exists somewhere.  Otherwise, it's mere speculation and opinion.

Comment: Based on context I believe the question being asked is "I don't understand why..." not "Why did Microsoft..." - definitely a good point regardless

Answer (score 3):

*Why is that?*

The currency symbol for invariant culture is `¤`, which is not a dollar sign. That's why it fails.

However, you do not need to modify the conversion code you have to account for this - but you can modify the string you pass in.

```
static string ReplaceCurrency(string str) 
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{Sc}", "¤");
}
```

This will replace any currency symbol with the invariant symbol - which will parse correctly.

```
string str = "$1,000.00";
double output;
var success = Double.TryParse(ReplaceCurrency(str), 
    NumberStyles.Currency, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    out output);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output

```
1000
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a notice with `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign`,you just need to do follow it,there you just use `new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { CurrencySymbol = "$" }` to replace your `null`

```
string str = "$1,000.00";
double output;
var success = Double.TryParse(
    str
    , NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
        | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint
        | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
        | NumberStyles.AllowExponent
        | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol
    , new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { CurrencySymbol = "$" }
    // or NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo break conversion with '$'..
    , out output
    );
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}, {2}", str, output, success);
```

As this is an amount, I would use decimal:

```
string str = "$1,000.00";
decimal output;
var success = decimal.TryParse(
    str
    , NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite
        | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
        | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint
        | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
        | NumberStyles.AllowExponent
        | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol
    , new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { CurrencySymbol = "$" }
    , out output
    );
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}, {2}", str, output, success);
```